# Should Angular and Laravel be seperate application or Laravel should serve angular app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, rest, laravel-4

I am going to create a big application, SAAS type.

Laravel & Angular has been decided to be used in the project. But I am new to both of these as I am cakephp background.

Now I am trying to take this decision. Whether should I keep both angular and Laravel a completely seperate projects. where Laravel is behaving purely as an API Or should I mix these both. I have seen people serving angular templates from laravel.

I'll have a mobile application for the same later, so that's another thing I have to keep in mind.

I am not sure if that's ok to ask such question here but I'll still appreciate any guidance on this here.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend separating them altogether. In this way, your projects/repos only contain one "environment" or context, which in my opinion makes everything cleaner. It also helps reusability, in that your API becomes completely app agnostic. You can of course still serve them from the same server.

Separating the components also make them easier to test in CI, because you'll only have to test one component at a time.

I'd recommend versioning the API, especially during early development, so that versions of the app can target a specific version of the API. Developing "API first" in iterations minimizes problems with compatibility between the two components as long as there are few breaking changes from the API side.

Comment: I feel the same. But just wondering if I'll get any benefit the other way, say if I mix those both.

Comment: One benefit could be that a snapshot or version of the API is closely tied together with a specific version of the app, but that could also backfire when development is done on one at a time.